# query over many to many relationship in redbeanphp

Tags: php, mysql, redbean

i have two tables which are "user" and "estate" and i make a many-many relation between those table with this code :

```
$user->link("estatetrans", (array("trtype" => $trtype, "indate" => time())))->estate = $estate;
```

> "estatetrans" is name of table that contain relation between these two table :

now i want query over "estatetrans" table by filtering on **trtype** column.

i do this action using this code :

```
$trans = R::findAll("estatetrans", "users_id=:uid and trtype=:trt" , array("uid"=>$userId , "trt"=>$trtype)) ; 
    $estates = array() ; 
    foreach ($trans as $tr)
    {
        array_push($estates, $tr->estate) ; 
    }
```

but i know it is not a perfect and good principal. 
how can i do this work by redbeanphp methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RedBeanPHP way would be to use the sharedList instead of findAll, for example, something like this:

```
list($e, $t) = R::dispenseAll('estate,transaction');
$e
  ->link('estate_transaction',['type'=>'auction'])
  ->transaction = $t;
R::store($e);
$e = R::findOne('estate');
$x = $e
     ->withCondition(' estate_transaction.type = ? ',['auction'])
     ->sharedTransaction;
```

$x now contains the transactions, filtered by the estate_transaction.type column.

Note that you can also rename the link table if you want an even fancier solution.

cheers
Gabor